# ¿Cómo asignar permisos a una carpeta en Linux?

Tags: sql, docker-compose

mi pregunta es ¿cómo dar permiso a la carpeta?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo dar permiso para poder seguir instalando para el contenedor docker?

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `sudo composer install` ?

Comment: yo estoy  sudo bash

Comment: Hola, un poco tarde... los permisos se modifican con ***chmod*** puedes buscar info [aquí](https://www.howtogeek.com/437958/how-to-use-the-chmod-command-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Se ve que estas usando el usuario www-data. Lo más sencillo es modificar el Dockerfile o buscar cual es el password root de la imágen base que usas.

Dockerfile

```
...
# Al principio del archivo 
USER root
RUN composer install
...
USER www-data
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tu usuario por default es www-data cámbiale el propietario a la carpeta con el siguiente comando

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Con eso debería ser suficiente.

Comment: Hola Junior, gracias por tu colaboración, te invito a que [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada y que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!